# #1023 StackOverflow ERROR

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have problem with this array thing I am doing. U can just plug in the code and run. 
I need to have 2 things display out of the same array and which ever is picked gets kickedout from the array and stashed into another one.

One of the 2 things that are displaying out is picked at random and the other one goes in order it was put in.

So the logic I applied, or tried applying and is not working very well is..

Once the 2 things display out and if u pick the index count, no numbers change since the index count becomes subtracted by one, so the object after it gets pushed up. 
 but if the random choice is picked the index count moves up by one since it needs to keep moving...

The error i get is this:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
    at Level3Torture_fla::MainTimeline/civilizedorder()[Level3Torture_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:87]
    at Level3Torture_fla::MainTimeline/goNext()[Level3Torture_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:114]
    at Level3Torture_fla::MainTimeline/switchpic()[Level3Torture_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:79]
```

This is the Code:

```
import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var eating_breakfast:Sprite;
var walking:Sprite;
var swimming:Sprite;
var art:Sprite;
var choices:Array = new Array ();

//Sprite Creation
eating_breakfast = new Sprite ();
eating_breakfast.graphics.beginFill(0xE39D43);
eating_breakfast.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
eating_breakfast.graphics.endFill();
eating_breakfast.x = 50;
eating_breakfast.y = 50;


walking = new Sprite ();
walking.graphics.beginFill(0xC3266C);
walking.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
walking.graphics.endFill();
walking.x = 100;
walking.y = 100;


swimming = new Sprite ();
swimming.graphics.beginFill(0x48AFD1);
swimming.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
swimming.graphics.endFill();
swimming.x = 150;
swimming.y = 150;


art = new Sprite ();
art.graphics.beginFill(0xafdb44);
art.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
art.graphics.endFill();
art.x = 200;
art.y = 200;

//adding sprites into array
choices.push( eating_breakfast);
choices.push(walking);
choices.push(swimming);
choices.push(art);


var indexcount = 0;
var randomize:Number;
var storageArray: Array = new Array ();
civilizedorder();
randomizedorder();
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,switchpic);

//pick the target generated object
function switchpic(t:MouseEvent)
{
    //for index count
    if (t.target == choices[indexcount])
    {
        storageArray.push(choices[indexcount]);
        removeChild(choices [indexcount]);
        removeChild(choices [randomize]);
        choices.splice(indexcount,1);
        goNext();

    };
    // for randomize
if (t.target == choices[randomize])
{
    storageArray.push(choices[randomize]);
    removeChild(choices [indexcount]);
    removeChild(choices [randomize]);
    choices.splice(randomize,1);
    indexcount++;
    trace("The Index count is" + indexcount);
    goNext();
}
}

//generates the index count object
function civilizedorder()
{

addChild(choices [indexcount]);
choices[indexcount].x = 300;


}
trace("The number of choices in the choice array is " + choices.length);
//generates the randomized object
function randomizedorder()
{

randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
trace("the random number is" + randomize);
if (randomize == indexcount )
{
    randomizedorder();
}
else
{
    addChild(choices [randomize]);
}

}
//EDIT

    function goNext()
{
    trace("The storagearray has " + (storageArray.length));
    if (choices.length < 0 || choices.length > 0)
    {
        if (indexcount > choices.length-1)
        {
            indexcount = choices.length - 1;
        }
        civilizedorder();
        randomizedorder();
    }
}
```

It is giving me a new error now. It's called StackOverflow. I am not entirely sure what is going wrong now.

Comment: What is the value of `indexcount` when `civilizedorder()` is called?

Comment: that depends on the choice.. if the person picked the box that was generated by indexcount it will remain same as previous but otherwise it needs to go up by one. The initial value needs to be 0. :D

Comment: Can you assert the value is never outside `0` to `3`?

Comment: yep.. The amount of objects going into the array are limited so I suppose. but how would I do that? will it also fix the problem?

Comment: I see 4-items in the array; therefore, if `indexcount` is outside that bounds then you're trying to add a `null` child to the display list, which would explain the error.

Comment: right.. so how do I limit the indexcount?

Comment: `trace(indexcount)` as the first statement in `civilizedorder()` to identify when and where the value is set outside the bounds.

Comment: But it also does this. When I pick the random object, the index doesn't move up it stays the same.. and another case is if I take pick the index object, random object and try to pick the index again it throws off the same error as well

Comment: it doesn't go out of bounds until like the last choice which is bad, but the bigger problem is, it's not working before that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: To add a conditional and check if you will be out of bounds for adding a child in this array, try this:**

```
if(indexcount <= choices.length){
  addChild(choices [indexcount]);
}
```

Try commenting out the splicing in the **switchpic()** method. That or re-add those values/sprite instances to the array.

I think that you've sliced from the "choices" array twice in the **switchpic()** method, and *never actually add to the array ever again*. So you'll eventually end up with an empty **choices** array. Hence the error.

In the second conditional, `if (t.target == choices[randomize])`, you increment **indexcount**, and then call **goNext()** which regenerates the randomize value to not equal the indexcount, but also tries to re-add a child sprite.

This could cause an array of 4 items to become 2 items, and then, possibly, randomize = 0, indexcount = 1. In the second pass, you might have an array of 0 items, with randomize = 0, indexcount = 1 and the error to occur.

Here's the flow, I imagine:

It looks like you're clicking on an instance of a sprite.

Then it calls **switchpic()**, which executes:

```
...
choices.splice(indexcount,1);
...
```

and then **goNext()**
which calls **civilizedorder()**

which executes:

```
...
addChild(choices [indexcount]);
...
```

Comment: Sorry i am new at this. so i have still a little bit problem understanding what u said. so please correct me if i say something opposite of what is written. once of the choices gets picked, it has to be removed from the array, because I cannot let it add again. I didn't really quite get the third paragraph. does it have a problem with it's order of operation? I am aware that it may not work once the array empties out, but it needs to work first when the array is full. How do I fix the last part that u wrote. I am sorry if it's amateur. I am just starting out thx for the answer.

Comment: Then add a conditional to check the size of the array. If you have an index that is trying to access outside the size of the array you need to gracefully handle it. That's defensive coding.

Answer (score 1):

you should check indexcount is never outside of 0-3 range. 
in function goNext(), change the code as follows:

```
function goNext()
{
    trace("The storagearray has " + (storageArray.length));
    if(choices.length <> 0)
    {
        if(indexcount > choices.length-1)    
            indexcount = choices.length-1;
        civilizedorder();
        randomizedorder();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot, it fixed objects coming in as null, but it's still showing the stackoverflow error. I am not totally positive on why it is occurring but it seems like, it thinks the array is empty once it passes over an object, and has trouble re-instantiating.